# place radio button in next line if no space

Tags: android

I am using RadioGroup in which orientation is horizantol, i am trying to place 5 radio button in this group, 3 radio buttons are comming fine, but remaining 2 are not coming, so is there any way that if space is not there then remaining radio button come in next line.

here is my code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/typePropertyRG"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noOfRoomsTxt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/room1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/room1"
          android:textColor="@drawable/buttun_text_color"

        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/room2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/buttun_text_color"
        android:text="@string/room2"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/room3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/buttun_text_color"
        android:text="@string/room3"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

      <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/room4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/buttun_text_color"
        android:text="@string/room4"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/room5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/buttun_text_color"
        android:text="@string/room4"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: if you need it may be you can use horizontalscrolview

Answer (score -1):

Just add weight in Radio buttons

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```